# Microsoft Graph API: $filter & $search not working together

Tags: c#, azure, outlook, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm using Graph API to look for a message in Inbox which has a particular subject and which is unread to download its attachment. I'm able to successfully search for messages with a particular subject using $search by forming this URL:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/myEmailId/mailFolders/Inbox/messages?$search=%22subject%3ASome%20Daily%20Email%22
```

And I'm able to successfully filter messages which are unread using this URL:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/myEmailId/mailFolders/Inbox/messages?$filter=isread%20eq%20false
```

But when I'm trying to combine both the query parameters, I get a Bad Request exception. I have tried using this URL :

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/myEmailId/mailFolders/Inbox/messages?$search=%22subject%3ASome%20Daily%20Email%22&$filter=isread%20eq%20false
```

I have tried (I know its stupid) inverse version by placing the $filter first and then $search. And I have also tried encoding the "&" in the URL.

Please let me know how to correctly call the URL by passing both $filter and $search together.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $filter parameter doesn't work with $search by design (see [Microsoft Graph optional query parameters](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/overview/query_parameters)):

> **Note**: You can currently search messages but not contacts or events. A **$search** request returns up to 250 results. You cannot use **$filter** or **$orderby** in a search request.

Comment: Oh..I completely missed the notes. So, I apparently cannot use $orderby and $filter with $search, neither can I use $orderby with $filter...working with Graph Apis sounds fun now..This question is now looking dumb but I'm accepting your answer because its correct. Thanks for your quick response.

Comment: Sorry, I know it doesn't help much just to say "you can't". Glad I could help.